# When to use "lo" and "le"?

Tags: gramática, pronombres, objetos-indirectos, objetos-directos, clíticos

When to use 'lo' and 'le'? Someone told me that 'le' is used in Spain and  'lo' is used in Latín America.

Is there a rule on when to use them?

Comment: There is some bad use of "le" when it should be "lo",  it's called "leísmo" and it's world-wide, but mainly in Spain. As "Yo le maté" instead of "Yo lo maté", "Yo le maté" would make reference to some object not named "Yo le maté (los piojos)" but still sounds strange (we say "Yo le maté los piojos = Yo se los maté").

Comment: This is a bit broad! Maybe some specific questions would've helped to give proper answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are talking about "[objeto directo](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_directo) & [objeto indirecto](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_indirecto)" ("complemento directo & complemento indirecto").

As an example:

> (Yo) Le di un regalo a Alberto / *I gave a present to Alberto*
>
> Yo le di un regalo / *I gave him a present* (you know who)
>
> Yo se lo di / *I gave it to him* (you know who and what you gave)

Another one:

> Ella compró un coche / *She bought a car*
>
> Ella lo compró / *She bought it* (you know what)
>
> Ella compró un coche a Juan / *She bought a car for Juan*
>
> Ella le compró un coche / *She bought him a car*
>
> Ella se lo compró / *She bought it for him*

Comment: "I gave a present to Alberto" should be translated as "Le di un regalo a Alberto". "Yo di un regalo a Alberto" is not idiomatic in Spanish.

Comment: You are right. I have edited it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Your question is a bit general but you have a nice table on the RAE website that can help you:

[RAE:pronombres átonos](https://www.google.es/search?q=rae+pronombres+atonos&sourceid=opera&btnI)

So for the third person you have:

- Complemento directo masculino singular: **lo**/(le(leísmo))
- Complemento directo masculino plural: **los**
- Complemento directo femenino singular: **la**
- Complemento directo femenino plural: **la**
- Complemento directo o atributo neutro singular: **lo**
- Complemento directo o atributo neutro plural: **-**
- Complemento indirecto singular: **le**
- Complemento indirecto plural: **les**

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, there are rules, but it is important to distinguish between the rules that govern Standard Spanish (which should be used in formal communication) and informal or dialectal Spanish — which still have rules, just different from the standard.

*In general*, the following table explains when to use each of the object pronouns in third person:

```
     +------+------+ 
     | Dir. | Ind. |
+----+------+------+
| ♂  | lo   | le   |
| ♂♂ | los  | les  |
| ♀  | la   | le   |
| ♀♀ | las  | les  |
| ⚲  | lo   | le   |
+----+------+------+
```

That said, there are circumstances where this table might change slightly and some of the changes are actually considered, due to their very high level of use, acceptable in Standard Spanish.

- ***Le*** instead of **lo/la**
  This is found across the Spanish-speaking world for a number of different reasons.  It is considered non-standard except in the following two exceptions:

  - When replacing a masculine and animate *lo*
  - When replacing *lo/la* that comes from *Vd.*
- ***Les*** instead of **los**
  Though the RAE recognizes that this is very common (especially by those that use *le* for *lo*), its usage is considered non-standard save for one exception:

  - When *los/las* stands for *Vds.*
- ***Lo*** instead of **le/les**
  This is always considered non-standard and not very common, but you do hear it once in a while. Mainly it's by people who speak Asturian/Leonese who use neuter *lo* for uncountable nouns in their language, or some Andean speakers whose native languages don't distinguish number/gender.
- ***La/las*** instead of **le/les**
  This is always considered non-standard and common primarily in central Spain. For these speakers, *le/les* is masculine only rather than ambiguous, and *la/las* become the feminine indirect object pronoun.