# Why is "lo" used in "lo único que obtendrás es..."?

Tags: gramática, pronombres, artículos

> Lo único que obtendrás es un mal descanso nocturno.

Why is *lo* used here?

*El* or *la* is used in this context.

Comment: Why do you think that masculine *el* or feminine *la* should be used?  What do you think the reason might be for the neuter *lo* being used or why do you think it shouldn't be used?

Comment: Perhaps the answers https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/4674/when-to-use-lo-and-le might help you.

Answer (score 1):

In this case **lo** is the neutral article (determiner):

*el* → masculine singular

*la* → feminine singular

***lo* → neutral singular**

*los* → masculine plural

*las* → feminine plural

All of these Spanish articles correspond to the form **THE** in English.

In your example there is nothing determining the gender of what is ***the only thing*** that you will obtain, therefore you use the neutral.

Compare:

**La única COSA** que obtendrás es un mal descanso nocturno.

**El único RESULTADO** que obtendrás es un mal descanso nocturno.

**lo** is normaly used when there is no noun determining the gender of the subject; anyway the concordance with the adjective should be done with the masculine (of the adjective).

Comment: and why is it in the subbjunctive

Comment: There is no subjunctive in your example, "obtendrás" is future, indicative, 2nd person, singular

Comment: Maybe you are referring to "RESULTADO", that's an homophonous form "EL **RESULTADO**" → noun (the result, the outcome). "HA **RESULTADO**" → past perfect (that has resulted). "QUE RESULTE" → subjunctive (that it results, that it turns out)